# input type="text" autofill_manager_delegate issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using Phonegap 2.9 with jquery-mobile, KitKat 4.4

If I want to type something in a `<input type="text" />`

I get following error in the LogCat:

Textareas are working, really strange. The problem is that I can't ignore it, because the value of the input type = "" - after adding content.

```
11-28 18:11:05.516: E/chromium(22253): [ERROR:aw_autofill_manager_delegate.cc(144)] Not implemented reached in virtual void android_webview::AwAutofillManagerDelegate::UpdateAutofillPopupDataListValues(const std::vector<std::basic_string<short unsigned int, base::string16_char_traits> >&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<short unsigned int, base::string16_char_traits> >&)
```

any ideas?

best

Comment: Do you find the solution , i am getting the error !?